# Number of processes a real time operating system can handle

Tags: operating-system, real-time

I was asked this question in a interview long time back in a design your own RTOS question. Is there a limitation to the number of processes a real time operating system can handle? What would cause this limitation? From what I know each process should have its own PC, call stack, heap, file descriptors, page tables, etc.. I assume the kernel has to keep track of the process using some data structure. Is the limitation derived from this data structure?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the amount of RAM available is the only limiting factor (as is the case in [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org)), however in a few cases there are limitations imposed by the chosen scheduling algorithm.  For example uCOS/II has (I think) a limitation of 255 because of the bitmap scheduler used - but even so 255 is more than you would ever need in a real time system of the type it is designed for.

Comment: I'm not sure how RAM can limit the number of processes for a RTOS. Isn't it simply that a program is loaded into memory and then swapped out? Even if the program is too big to fit in memory, it can make use of swap space on disk so RAM shouldn't limit the number of processes? With the scheduler bitmap I can understand it.